# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException String vs java.lang.String

Tags: string, groovy

I was doing a coding challenge that prints a given text in a zig-zag:

thisisazigzag:

```
t     a     g
 h   s z   a
  i i   i z
   s     g
```

So I have my code (not sure if it's right or not yet, but that's not part of the question)

```
class Main { 

    public void zigzag(String text, int lines) {
        String zigLines = [];
        while(lines > 0){
            String line = "";
            increment = lines+(lines-2);
            lines = lines + (" " * (lines-1));
            for(int i=(lines-1); i<text.length(); i+=increment) {
                line = line + text[i] + (" " * increment);
            }
            zigLines.add(0, line);
            lines--;
        }
        for(line in zigLines){
            println(line);
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        zigzag("thisisazigzag", 4);
    }
}
```

But when I run the script, I keep getting this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Main.zigzag() 
  is applicable for argument types: (String, Integer) values: [thisisazigzag, 4]
Possible solutions: zigzag(java.lang.String, int)
```

And I'm very confused as to the difference between `java.lang.String` and `String` and then `Integer` and `int`?

Any help or explanation of this would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to make the method zigzag static?

Comment: I just did... and that worked..... Now I'm curious why does `static` make it work vs. fail miserably?

Comment: Without the static modifier zigzag was an instance method, meaning you would need an instance of your class Main to be able to call it. Here's an introductory tutorial explaining some of these concepts: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @delephin can you post that as the answer, and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your `zigzag` method `static`.

Your code wasn't working because without the `static` modifier `zigzag` was an instance method, meaning you would need an instance of your class Main to be able to call it. Here's an introductory tutorial explaining some of these concepts: [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Thanks @delephin for this.